# XCheckMaskEvent for ButtonMotionMask only returns pointer position of (0,0)

Tags: c, linux, debian, x11

Using the X11 library on debian jessie, I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
Display *display;
XEvent xevent;
Window window;
int x,y;
#define BUTTON1MOTION (1L<<8)

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if( (display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL )
        return -1;
    //int curr = 0;
    while (1) {
        XCheckMaskEvent(display, ButtonMotionMask, &xevent);
        printf("x_root: %d y_root: %d \n", xevent.xmotion.x_root, xevent.xmotion.y_root);
    }
}
```

I would like to capture MotionNotify events associated with the mouse being moved. However, the XCheckMaskEvent returns an endless stream of Motion events, even when no mouse buttons are pressed and no motion is done on the mouse; and x,y coordinates for these events are always (0,0). What can I do to get genuine mouse movement events, with the correct coordinates?

PS. use the -lX11 tag for compilation, i.e. `gcc -Wall -lX11`

EDIT: I used XCheckMaskEvent which works as it automatically returns, unlike the former, but this returns an endless stream of events even if the mouse is not moving.

Answer (score 0):

From https://linux.die.net/man/3/xcheckmaskevent

> The XCheckMaskEvent function searches the event queue and then any events available on the server connection for the first event that matches the specified mask. If it finds a match, XCheckMaskEvent removes that event, copies it into the specified XEvent structure, and returns True.

This function does *not* wait for such an event. Now imagine what your program does when no event matching `ButtonMotionMask` is in the event queue.

> and x,y coordinates for these events are always (0,0).

You are reading an unintialised variable.

Comment: So are you implying somewhere in those coordinates of (0,0)s there were actually button movements with non-zero values, corresponding to when I moved the mouse?
Or that the wrong mask was used?

Comment: I was trying to say "your program does not do what you want it to do at all". You have a busy loop that interprets zero-initialised memory as motion events. Your code only checks the X11 event queue for ButtonMotion events, which will never be there, because you did not ask the X11 server for any motion events. What I should also have said: You need to call `XSelectInput` to ask the X11 server for events.